# Eclipse project properties missing Classpath tab

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Helios Service Release 2. When I try to configure my build path in the project properties, I do not have a Classpath tab. Has anyone experienced this and/or know how to fix it? I can set the classpath in the .classpath file in the project root, however, not everyone on my team wants to do it this way, and I cannot find a solution.

Plugins installed:

---

Subclipse

PyDev

Jamaica ME CDC Tools

Collabnet Merge Client

Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x

Subversion Client Adapter

Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter

Subversion Revision Graph

SVNKit Client Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in Helios R2 the classpath configuration is done when you set up your run configuration. The issues I was having were fixed once I set the appropriate settings here.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your project is not a java project. Check your .project file and see if you can find the java builder

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

and the java nature

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
```

Comment: Yeah these pieces are in there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what "Classpath tab" you are referring to, but to edit contents of .classpath file, head over to Project Properties -> Java Build Path.

Comment: This is the place where it should be, but I cannot find it.