# Using a remote git resource in eclipse for a runnable java project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, github

My problem currently is that I've got a project on bitbucket, and I've been able to create a local repository of the project through Eclipse.

However, when attempting to import the repository into Eclipse to run the project I come up against a couple of issues.

1. **Create a new project from the git repository.**
   This does create a new project and links it to the local repo, but I'm not able to run is as a java project. The reason being that all of the options under the 'run configurations' are blank. And Eclipse doesn't recognise the project as a project at all.
2. **Create a java project first, and link it to the repo such that I can
   do push and pull to the repo**. No idea how.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option 1/, it could be as simple as to [add the Java Nature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6624793/6309) to your current project (as [seen also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6534212/6309)).

Regarding the option 2/, you could create your java project, and then:

- delete the project from your workspace (soft delete only, you wouldn't delete the files on the hard drive)
- move the project files (ie .the .project, .classpath and sources) to the local git repo
- import that project (in its new location) in your Eclipse workspace.
- right click on them, select `Team-> Share-> Git` (and select your Git repo location), in order to mention to Eclipse that this project is managed by Git.

Comment: Good tutorials on Egit: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html and http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide

Comment: that did the trick. I was missing the .project and .classpath files in the repo. Which was why I couldn't execute it as a java app.

Comment: @user1249379: Excellent! Creating a Java project (ie generating the right `.project` and `.classpath`) and then copying said project files in your Git repo is certainly easier than trying to add Java nature to those same files (as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070017/how-to-import-a-git-non-eclipse-java-project-into-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

I think importing the repository into Eclipse and running the project are different things.

To simplify the process, I always use "git clone xxx" to get a local repository. Then add an existing local git repository into Eclipse and create an existing java project from the cloned git repository respectively. In this way, I can run my project and control the repository.